# Representing game board for connect 4 in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make an interactive, text-based connect4 game in SWI Prolog, and I'm a little stuck on how to start. What I don't understand is how to represent the game board, since I don't think I can have arrays, or variables that can be seen and modified by all rules.

Any insight as to how to start would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An appropriate representation of a data structure amenable to your situation is often half the problem in PROLOG.

There are many ways of representing things in a grid like a 2-dim array in PROLOG, but I'd argue that the easiest are probably list-based, since there is a lot of inherent support for list structures:

**1. List-of-lists.** E.g., for a 3x3, `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`. Your interpretation of this structure will be inherent in your code to traverse and manipulate it (i.e., `[a,b,c]` can be a row, or a column, it's up to you, just be consistent). To access an individual cell, you'd need to traverse the structure with a predicate that counts (or matches to) particular positions.

**2. List-of-terms.** E.g., `[cell(0,0,a), cell(0,1,b), ..., cell(2,2,i)]`. This would allow you to pull out individual cells directly, such as via `select(cell(1,2,Value), L, Rem)` to extract the `Value` of cell at position `1,2` from the list of cells, `L`, allowing you to manipulate it and create the full list again by creating a new `cell/3` term and appending it to `Rem`.

I would advise against using the `assert`/`retract` mechanism in writing code to handle this problem; it's messy, unnecessary, and not conducive to writing easily understandable and 'debuggable' PROLOG code.

Comment: +1 for recommending against assert/retract. Btw, may I ask why you write Prolog in all-caps?

Answer (score 1):

(I hope you are talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) game).

You have a several choices.

You can have a list of lists for the whole field, like
 [[empty,empty,yellow,red,empty],[red,red,red,yellow,yellow],[red,red,red,red,red]].

Or you can assert/retract facts like

red(2, 4).
red(1, 3).
yellow(2, 2).
red(3, 2).

The game is simple, so choose whatever matches your intuitive representation.